# Sending Mass Emails

Tags: email

I have a massive list of users who registered for accounts and opted into a mailing list on my web site and I am interested in sending out a weekly newsletter. How should I go about doing this. I tried sending it out through my host server, but I received a notice stating that if I did it again they would kick me off the server. Are there any good companies that are designed for this type of thing? I need to find a company that will support this and show me some sort of report about how many emails get opened, deleted, opened then deleted, etc. Any recommendations?

Comment: How many is "massive"?

Comment: If you're looking for recommendations please ask in [chat]

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that's definitely whats going to happen if you just email through your ISP without first letting them know. Most providers have automatic limit set and if you cross it, they will definitely kick you or suspend your account. So first of all, what you need is some type of software to manage your list and manage your bounce back and the replies. For example you can look up advanced emailer on Google, then you need to  split your list into parts and send them separately once a day at least for the first time. If you haven’t sent anything to your list for a long time, there will be a lot of dead emails on that list. So it is very critical to watch it closely when you send your email for the first time because you will have a lot of bounce backs. After you get them, clean them from your email list immediately because they will get this type of response from your provider all the time. If you have generally more than 5-10% of those bad emails, providers tend to kick you, ban your account or suspend it until you call them. To actually send this email itself, you need to go to some email sending provider like smtp.com or sendgrid and talk to them first. Go on the phone, talk to them and explain the situation. SMTP.com for example has consultants that would be able to talk to you and accommodate your requests. After your list is clean, you will be able to send on a much more regular basis. Of course you will have some unsubscribes and some emails going bad, but it’s not going to be anywhere near as when you send for the first time. So keep your communication with your clients active.

Now about reporting question, you cannot know if your client deletes your email. There is no way to report that. And also when they open your email, the report on that not very reliable because it is based on the fact that software embeds a one by one pixel image into your email. But in most cases, your email client doesnt even render the images, they dont even go through. They become dots or empty holes on your email. For example the biggest email clients are set up like this by default. The only thing you can really track is how many people click on the links embedded in your email. And that is very easy to do. You dont need anything extra, you can just use Google analytics to track how many people click on this particular page. And this will show you reliable numbers on the effectiveness of your campaign.